# Google Script - script timed out

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know much about programming but I created a script for one of my spreadsheets which worked very well a few months ago.
But lately it is impracticable to use any script, however simple it may be. Sometimes it runs perfectly in 1 or 2 seconds and most of the time it just times out and fails. 90% of executions result in "timed out".

In summary, the function must be executed every time column B or C of the spreadsheet is edited. For this I used the function OnEdit ().
When column B is edited, the date and time is inserted in column D in the respective line where the change occurred.
When column C is edited, the date and time is inserted in column E in the respective line where the change occurred.

Here is the code:

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var aba = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();



 if (column == 2 && aba == "Controle")
  {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell();

     if(cell.getValue() != "")
     {
      var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm' '");
        add.setValue(data);
     }
     else
     {
       var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = "";
        add.setValue(data);
     }
  }
  if (column == 3 && aba == "Controle")
  {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
      
      if(cell.getValue() == true)
      {
        var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm' '");
        add.setValue(data);
      }
      else
      {
        var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = "";
        add.setValue(data);
      }
  }
}
```

Even super simple recorded macros like applying a filter are showing this problem.

I would like to know if there is something that can be done in the code to make it more efficient to solve this problem or if the timeout problem reached is related to something else.

Thanks

Comment: English is common language here.

Comment: Simple triggers like this must complete with in 30 seconds.  You might try an installable trigger I don't know what they're maximum execution time is.  You could  streamline your code a bit by learning how to take maximal advantage of the event object parameters.  To learn more place this code near the beginning of the function. Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) and see the results in the execution logs

Comment: Here is the report:

{"user":"email":"","nickname":""},"oldValue":"false","source":},"authMode":"LIMITED","value":"TRUE","range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":91,"rowStart":91}}

Maximum execution time exceeded

I can't get through the debugger because it gives an error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Código.gs:5**

This error only occurs in the debugger. If I run directly through the spreadsheet this error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Controle' && e.range.columnStart>1 && e.range.columnStart<4)  {
    if(e.range.columnStart==2) {
      if(e.value='') {
        e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm' '"));
      }else{
        e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());                           
      }
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart==3) {
      if(e.value==true) {
        e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm' '"));
      }else{
        e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.
It seems not to be related to the code but to something else.
The spreadsheet is shared with at least 3 people and edits are made frequently (approximately 10 edits per minute and in a row). Would it be a limit set by google for requesting scripts too much? I really don't know, because sometimes everything runs correctly and fast and suddenly everything stops.
I didn't find anyone having the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work.  Please provide more explanation

Comment: My experience with onEdits is that if you have too many people making simultaneous edits that it won't be able to keep up.  You might be able to get away with using an installable trigger and lock service.  But my guess is that it's not worth the trouble.  I think it's always going to have trouble keeping up with  peoples typing speed.  The only time I ever use this is when there's only one person running it.

Comment: I prefer to use a web interface for users.  That way you can funnel them through the  same read and write functions and use lock service to disallow simultaneous usage of the same script.

Comment: **"What do you mean by it didn't work. Please provide more explanation"**

Sorry, I'll explain it better. Your code worked perfectly. Thank you, much more efficient. However, the time-out problem remains.
I think it must be because it is being used by multiple users as you described yourself.

Comment: Try the other answer and let me know if that works for you.  It would be nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs, your script is reaching quota for exceeding maximum execution time, although it is also possible from your scenario to have more than 30 simultaneous executions, which will make the script fail to run too.

One workaround, as Cooper have said in the comments, is to implement a lock on parts of the script, especially on sections that make changes to the spreadsheet, to make subsequent executions wait on one script to complete.

**Sample code:**

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var aba = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();

  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  
  try { lock.waitLock(10000); } // wait 10 sec

 if (column == 2 && aba == "Controle")
  {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell();

     if(cell.getValue() != "")
     {
      var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm' '");
        add.setValue(data);
     }
     else
     {
       var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = "";
        add.setValue(data);
     }
  }
  if (column == 3 && aba == "Controle")
  {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
      
      if(cell.getValue() == true)
      {
        var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm' '");
        add.setValue(data);
      }
      else
      {
        var add = cell.offset(0, 2);
        var data = new Date();
        data = "";
        add.setValue(data);
      }
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // applies all pending spreadsheet changes
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

**References:**

[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

[Class Lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)

Comment: Using lock service did not solve it.
I removed the shares and even just me editing the problem persists.
I saw that there really is a limit of 30 simultaneous operations, but even when I do just one, the problem persists.
I managed to improve a little using the installable trigger. For some reason it is more persistent and does not terminate the script before completing it. Sometimes it takes approximately 100 seconds per run.
Sometimes the scripts are executed in less than 2 seconds and then are delayed again. I can't find an explanation.

Comment: At least for the installable trigger, even if it takes a while to run without showing "time out".
Another thing that improved, I don't know if it was a coincidence, I removed some array formulas from a sheet on the side. For some reason it has improved, even though this sheet has no direct relationship with the data worked on the script. I don't know, but it has improved.

Thanks for the help Carlos and Cooper